# Why is my field validated even if it's not required?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a request that takes several input. I want the 'salary' input to be validated **only** if the salary_type is equal to "exact". Else, I don't want to have any message about it.

However, now, even if salary_type is equal to "range", I still get an error that "salary must be an integer".

How can I make sure there isn't any error unless the field is required?

Thanks!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreJobOfferRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string|min:3',
            'description' => 'required|string|min:10',
            'city' => 'required|string|min:3',
            'salary_type' => 'required|in:range,exact',
            'min_salary' => 'required_if:salary_type,range|integer|min:0',
            'max_salary' => 'required_if:salary_type,range|integer|min:0',
            'salary' => 'required_if:salary_type,exact|integer|min:0',
            'fieldsOfWork' => 'required|exists:field_of_works,id',
            'job_type.*' => 'required|exists:job_types,id',
            "trainings.*" => 'required|exists:trainings,id',
            "availability.*" => 'required|exists:trainings,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`required` and `required_if` do not stop the rest of the validation rules from being executed. It just expects the value not to be `null`, an empty string, and empty `Countable` object or an uploaded file with no path. If the field is set, the required rule will just be skipped and the next rule is applied.

So, the `required_if` rule for `salary` will skip if `salary_type` is not `'exact'`, and continue validating if it's an integer and min 0. This behavior is confusing to a lot of new Laravel developers.

There is an `exclude_if` rule that does what you probably expect:

```
'salary' => 'exclude_if:salary_type,exact|integer|min:0',
```

This will exclude the whole field under validation from the request data that will be returned by `validate()` and `$request->validated()` methods if the condition is not met. So if `salary_type` is not `'exact'`, the `salary` field will be gone but the validation will pass.

If `salary_type` is `'exact'`, however, it will be validated for being a min 0 integer value.

Please note that the `exclude_if` rule was added in Laravel 6, so this doesn't work for previous versions of Laravel. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules for details on conditional validation.